# Git rebase removed lines added by another PR

Tags: git, git-rebase

I ran into a strange problem and I want to understand what happened:

We have a `develop` branch, where a colleague and I based a new feature branch from: `feature-a` and `feature-b`.

In his branch (`feature-a`) he added lines to `foo.js` (say: lines 100-120).
In my branch (`feature-b`) I removed lines in `foo.js` (say: lines 90-110).

His feature got merged into `develop` and I rebased my branch off `develop` afterwards.

There were no merge conflicts, but when everything was said and done, his lines were not there anymore.

I suspect what happened was:

1. Lines 100-120 were added from `feature-a` to `develop`
2. My work (remove 90-110) was replayed on top
3. 90-110 was now actually 90-130, because of the 20 added lines
4. Those lines were removed in `feature-b`

I actually expected git to be smart enough to not do this and leave the "new" lines in. Isn't that the correct assumption?

Is there a good way to check what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that, given your description, you should have gotten a merge conflict during rebasing.  To find out if you did not and why not, you can repeat the rebase, perhaps breaking it down into commit-by-commit copies.

Running `git rebase` runs either a repeated sequence of `git cherry-pick` operations, or one big `git am --3way` that applies a mailbox file of patches produced by `git format-patch`.  Either way, this *copies* the original commits to newer, supposedly-better, commits.

Note that all commits are read-only.  This means that *nothing can change existing commits*.  Your existing commits, pre-rebasing, are untouched by rebase!  The trick is *finding* the original commits.  With no obvious names by which to find them, Git will eventually (after 30 days by default) *remove* them.

#### Draw what you started with

Let's take a look at a typical example, drawing in some commits whose hash IDs are recorded by your various branch names.  We don't know the commit's hash IDs, but they're too unwieldy anyway, so we'll just use uppercase letters:

```
...--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- develop
             |\
             | H--I   <-- feature-a
             \
              J--K   <-- feature-b (HEAD)
```

Here, you are on `feature-b` and you have two commits `J` and `K` that are unique to your work.  Your colleage is on `feature-a` and also has two commits.  You both share commit `G` as a base you both started from; commit `G` is on branch `develop` as well as on both of your feature branches.  Commit `G` is specifically the *tip commit* of `develop` at this time.  Commit `F` is on all three branches as well; `F` points back to (records the hash ID of) `E`, which is the tip of `master`.  `E` points back to `D`, and so on all the way to the very first commit in the repository.  Commits `E` and earlier are on all four branches at this point.

Let's say that in commit `I` he added those lines to `foo.js`, so that snapshot `H` does not have the lines, and snapshot `I` does.  His feature is now approved, so someone in some repository, which has branch names that are very similar and point to the same commits, does these two commands:

```
git checkout develop
git merge feature-a     # or maybe git merge --no-ff feature-a
```

The first one attaches their `HEAD` to their name `develop`, so that the merge result will be added or saved there.  The second does a real merge if `--no-ff` is specified or if a real merge is required, or does a fast-forward operation if possible and not prohibited.  I'll assume fast-forward for simplicity, so that the result is:

```
...--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G
              \
               H--I   <-- develop (HEAD), feature-a
```

(I've left your commits out entirely here, assuming they have not been pushed; it does not affect the outcome either way.)

in their repository.  If you now run `git fetch origin` to obtain *their* state, you wind up with this in your own repository:

```
...--D--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G   <-- develop
             |\
             | H--I   <-- origin/develop, feature-a, origin/feature-a
             \
              J--K   <-- feature-b (HEAD)
```

Note that your `origin/*` names are copies of *their* names, changed to be remote-tracking names instead of branch names.  Like your branch names, these remote-tracking names point to *tip* commits.  Your `git fetch` step does this to make sure that your own branch names are not affected.

#### Watch a rebase happen

You can now run `git rebase origin/develop` or `git rebase origin/feature-a` or even (in this particular case) `git rebase feature-a`, since all that we care about is picking the correct *commit*.  This will:

1. enumerate all your (non-merge) commits reachable from `HEAD` that are not reachable from the target commit: that's `J` and `K`;
2. check out the target commit: that's `I`;
3. cherry-pick or otherwise copy the commits enumerated in step 1;
4. move the branch name.

To copy a commit, Git essentially turns it into a set of changes, by comparing the commit with its parent.  So for `J`, Git compares the snapshot in `G` with the snapshot in `J`.  Whatever you changed there, Git does the same thing to the current commit, then makes a new commit.  Let's call the new commit `J'`:

```
...--D--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G   <-- develop
             |\
             | H--I   <-- origin/develop, feature-a, origin/feature-a
             |     \
             |      J'  <-- temporary HEAD
             \
              J--K   <-- feature-b
```

Git repeats the copy for `K`, by comparing `J` vs `K` and applying the same changes to `J'`:

```
...--D--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G   <-- develop
             |\
             | H--I   <-- origin/develop, feature-a, origin/feature-a
             |     \
             |      J'-K'  <-- temporary HEAD
             \
              J--K   <-- feature-b
```

Now that all the commits are copied, rebase finishes up by "peeling the label" `feature-b` off commit `K` and making it point to commit `K'` instead:

```
...--D--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G   <-- develop
             |\
             | H--I   <-- origin/develop, feature-a, origin/feature-a
             |     \
             |      J'-K'  <-- feature-b (HEAD)
             \
              J--K   [abandoned]
```

Now that there's no *name* for your commit `K`, it is hard for you to find it.

#### Something went wrong, so identify what and figure out why

One of your commits deleted some lines.  You believe that copying that commit deleted *too many* lines.  Now that you can see how each commit was copied, you can:

1. Find the hash IDs of your original commits.

   This can be a bit tricky.  The name for them, `feature-b`, no longer points to them.  It points to the copies instead.  There are several alternatives though:

   - `ORIG_HEAD`: `git rebase` sets this name to point to the original final commit (`K` in our drawing above).  However, this name gets re-used by other operations as well, so it may no longer point to your original chain.  You can check to find out.
   - Reflogs: each branch has a *reflog*, and there's one for `HEAD` as well.  Running `git reflog` will show you the one for `HEAD`; running `git reflog feature-b` will show you the one for `feature-b`.  The reflog remembers which commit the branch name *used to point to*, and remembers this for at least 30 days.  Look at the reflog for your `feature-b` to find which commits you had *before* the rebase copied them.
2. Repeat the copy operation so you can see just what happened.

   Now that you have the originals and know where your branch names used to point (using their various reflogs), you can find all the original commits, which are still in their original states.

   You can then `git checkout` (as a detached HEAD) whichever commit came right before something went wrong, then use `git cherry-pick` or `git format-patch -1 <hash> --stdout | git am --3way` to copy it, just as `git rebase` did.

While this should just do the same (wrong) thing as before, you now have enough details to ask a more specific question: *Why did copying this commit atop this specific snapshot result in this specific breakage?*

Comment: Thanks for this incredible write-up! I'm not sure if I 100% follow, as I'm just not that good with git, but it does clarify some of the inner workings and at least allows me to identify where things went awry.

I will try and identify what really happened!